# Use in-memory buffer as a file

Tags: node.js, linux, file, in-memory

During my program's execution I get a buffer that I need to additionally feed into an external program and read it's output. Unfortunately, this program only accepts filenames as input and output, so I'd have to save this buffer to a disk first, but I'd like not to create temp files on the filesystem, if that's possible.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: On linux file is not the same as data stored on disk. A file is an abstract thing, and in fact it can be stored in memory. There are at least two tools (file systems) that you can use for that: tmpfs and ramfs. From a program's perspective there is no difference between a file stored on disk, or a file stored in memory. You just need a path, that's all. Note however that installing tmpfs/ramfs requires administrative rights.

Comment: depending on your case you may also want to use named pipes - see for example https://www.baeldung.com/linux/anonymous-named-pipes